# Getting the Current Location

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cllocationmanager

Say I want to create a function

```
-(void)setCurrentLocationasAnchor
{
    //[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

It's job is to set `self.currentAnchor` into the current location.

How would I do that?

The only thing I can think of is do `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` and then wait until the  delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

is called.

How can I do so in one function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any problem in particular in just doing it the way you said? (i.e. waiting for the delegate to be called)

Because if what you want is a synchronous way of getting the location, that'd be blocking the UI, right?... Also, what do you want, just the first location to be returned? Because the longer you wait, the more precision you will get on your location.

Btw, have you considered using CLLocationManager's [location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) property to get a recent location?

Comment: Yea synchronizity is easier to program. Let me check

Comment: So I just turn location on all the time and use that. Make sense.

Comment: I didn't say turn it on all the time, it depends on what you want to do with it. If you just want to get "the current location" and don't care about keeping it permanently up-to-date, after you get a location with a precision that you're happy with you should stop monitoring the location.